# Decent interactive TCL shell

Tags: tcl

Is there anything like the iPython notebook for TCL?

Or at the very least, a shell that lets me use ctrl-f, ctrl-b, ctrl-a etc. without filling the shell with ^B etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [`tkcon`](http://tkcon.sourceforge.net/)

I like `rlwrap tclsh` -- see if your OS's package repository has it, or get it from [github](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap)