# Is there a way to go back to a previous line inside a proc in the TCL shell?

Tags: tcl, tclsh

After pressing enter when writing an erroneous statement inside a proc in tcl shell, is it possible to avoid writing that entire statement again?

Note: I am not using any TCL IDE here, directly writing in the shell.

```html
systest> tclsh
%proc demo {args} {
  set res #erroneous statement written in the shell
  set result 1 
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Why not copy from a text editor and paste when it looks good?

Comment: You might want to try the `tkcon` shell, which offer some editing capability such as arrow keys, tab completion.

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend tkcon instead of tclsh when playing with tcl. In tkcon you can simply finish the function (press `}` then enter) then do `edit demo` and it will open an editor where you can edit the proc. It's not just procs, you can also edit variables and files on your disk.

Comment: Thanks, tkcon it is!

Answer (score 2):

The basic tclsh does not have any features.

Maybe this [Decent interactive TCL shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743621/decent-interactive-tcl-shell) will help you...

The readline wrapper looks like a solution for you.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what shell and terminal you're using. If it's standard tclsh running in a terminal (whether Unix or Windows), the answer is *no*. The editing code just isn't that sophisticated. (You've got more options if you're using tkcon or a readline wrapper.)

Fortunately, if you're in the middle of writing a procedure it's no big deal. All you have to do is define that procedure again afterwards and the new one will just replace the old. It helps if you use copy-and-paste to get the correct pieces from where you were typing before. I do this sort of thing a lot; it lets me make sure that code snippets I use when helping people here are (well, almost) always tested.

Comment: "well, almost" -- amen brother!